# Unable to run solution after build in Visual Studio for Mac and Asp.net Core 2.0 Web API

Tags: asp.net, macos, visual-studio-2017, command-line-interface

I was a bit tired of my slow running pc, which has Visual Studio 2017. So, I shifted my code of Mac where I have Visual Studio 2017 for Mac, after restoring dependencies it built properly, but when running, it gives the exception below:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Libuv.Internal.Networking.UvException has been thrown

error -13 EACCES permission denied
```

So, I tried to run dotnet from terminal to find the root cause of the error with this:

```
dotnet run
```

Now, I it throws exception as below:

Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingProvider[48]

```
      An error occurred while reading the key ring.
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path '/Users/apple/.aspnet/DataProtection-Keys/42cb81a7-89b6-4a29-86ae-76d3acca3076.tmp' is denied. ---> System.IO.IOException: Permission denied
```

So, this is the error where permission is required to access this path, so what I tried is this:

```
sudo dotnet run
```

Which is running perfectly.

Now the question is, how can I run this within Visual Studio Mac? I need to debug and walkthrough the code many times.

Comment: Why don't you try to use IDE Rider for Mac? It's more comfortable to use than VS for Mac. But both of them is like a beta, though.

Comment: it is paid version where I am using community edition of VS. I am working with VS in windows from many years so pretty much comfortable with that.

Comment: i am able to run from this command sudo /Applications/Visual\ Studio.app/Contents/MacOS/VisualStudio but I have to launch it from terminal every time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run this command in terminal: This will open Visual Studio with Admin privileges and it works like charm.

```
sudo /Applications/Visual\ Studio.app/Contents/MacOS/VisualStudio
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to enable ***Root User Account***.

This [link](http://osxdaily.com/2012/01/09/enable-root-user-account-os-x-lion/) may be helpful, though.